# Matrix Printing using Pointers

Tags: c++, function, pointers, matrix

I am stuck with this problem and I really need some help. I have a function 
void f(int *a, int m, int n) and  it should print all the elements using pointers.
I tried

```
for(i = 0; i < m; ++i)
        for(j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            cout << *((a+i)+j);
```

but it doesn't print the right elements. Please help me.

In the main function I declare the matrix then I read the elements.

```
int col, rand, i, j;
    int a[100][100];
    cout << " col = ";
    cin >> col;
    cout << " rand = ";
    cin >> rand;

    for(i = 0; i < rand; ++i)
        for(j = 0; j < col; ++j)
    {
        cout << "a[" << i << "]" << "[" << j << "] = ";
        cin >> *(*(a+i)+j);
    }
```

when I try to print the elements from the main function everything is alright.

```
for(i = 0; i < rand; ++i)
        for(j = 0; j < col; ++j)
            cout << *(*(a+i)+j);

f(*a, col, rand); // function calling in the main function
```

Comment: `a[1]  = *(a+1)`, `a[1][2] = *(*(a+1)+2)`.. apply this to your problem and you'll be fine.

Comment: it gives me an error, invalid type argument, the matrix is passed like a pointer, so the elements can't be accessed like that.

Comment: The code you posted gives multiple errors, too, so the elements can't be accessed the way you've described. While it's possible to guess what it is that you're talking about, programming isn't about guessing. Post a small, complete example that compiles and runs and demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
cout << *(a+i*(p+1)+j);
```

But I think the below will also work.   (The relationship between `m` and `n` vs `r` and `p` needs clarification.

```
for(i = 0; i <= r; ++i)
    for(j = 0; j <= p; ++j)
        cout << *a++;
```

Comment: For 1, 2, 3, 4 it prints 1 2 0 0, I edited the first post, my fault.

Comment: Notice that your function cout statement differs from you main() cout: `cout << *((a+i)+j);` vs. `cout << *(*(a+i)+j);`.  Recommend you edit your post to include more of the function and how you called it.